# How to find the value of a cell in another tab based on cell criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Wholesale market price in a list on a sheet called 'DataBank'
Name of the product is column W & Price in column X

In a seperate tab called 'Position Activity' I have a drop down list in column AL based on the values of column W of the 'DataBank' sheet

When selecting the product in the dropdown list I would like the corresponding price to populate the cell next to the drop down list in column AK

Is there any help on offer for this? ideally in a script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. The dropdown list is the column "AL" or "AK"? And, what is `a drop down list in column AL based on the values of column W of the 'DataBank' sheet`? The dropdown list has the same values of the column "W" of `DataBank` sheet? Or the dropdown list has the diffrent values from the column "W" of `DataBank` sheet? And, where is `the cell next to the drop down list in column AK`? It's column "AL" or "AJ"?

Comment: Why not use a VLOOKUP of the values in AL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the formula I'd put in cell next to the dropdown list:
`=INDEX('DataBank'!X2:X;MATCH(AK2;'DataBank'!W2:W;0))`

`INDEX` and `MATCH` offer more flexibility than `VLOOKUP` when it comes to data format and the order/or how random the columns are.
Not tested.